# Generate array from 0 to N with custom increment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

#### Problem Description

I am trying to generate an array using `keys()` and `.map()` methods, given a preexisting array with `length = arrLength`, such that only items at a position that are multiples of `step` are generated. Here is an example,

```js
const arrLength = 20;
const step = 5;

const newArr = [...Array(arrLength).keys() ].map((i) => i + step);

console.log(newArr) ;
// expected: 0,5,10,15,20
// recieved : 5,6,7,...,24
```

I am particlarly confused as to how to increment the left hand side variable `i` in `map((i) => ... )`.

#### Restrictions

I want to implement this in one line using the `keys` method and `Array` and possibly `map`, so no `for` loop.

#### Things I have tried

I tried the following signatures instead

```
    Array(arrLength).fill().map((_, i) => i+step) ,
    Array.from(Array(arrLength), (_, i) => i+step),
    Array.from({ length: arrLength }, (_, i) => i+step)
```

but with no success. I have further tried to find a way to increment the `i` variable using functional syntax but with no success as wel.

Comment: I think you should try i*step not +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arrLength = 20;
const step = 5;
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i<= arrLength; i+=step){
  arr.push(i);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Or

```js
const arrLength = 20;
const step = 5;

const newArr = [...Array(Math.floor(arrLength/step) + 1).keys() ].map((i) => i * step);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: No sorry I cannot use a `for` loop, I need to do it in one line with `keys()` method and `Array`. I will clarify in the post.

Comment: @hexaquark I add another one.

Answer (score 2):

`range` function work with ES4
Using `Array.from` can pass an object has property length in it

```js
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
console.log(range(0, 20, 5))
```

Comment: This does not work for ranges in the negative space

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this, and while looking at the answers I came up with this. This just basically creates an array with incrementing numbers, but could be extended easily.

This `reduce` function generates desired array by taking the index `i` of given element and then we combine what we already got in the previous recursive step (the `a` variable) with the incremental value `i`.

```js
const arr = new Array(52).fill(0).reduce((a,_,i) => [...a, i],[])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but why not just this?

```
const step = 5;
const result = [...Array(10).keys()].map( i => i * step );

console.log(result);
```